# Oracle inner join give wrong result set

Tags: sql, oracle

When I execute this query it gives a 10 result set .

> select * from OA_SERVICE_REQUESTS  WHERE
>   OA_SERVICE_REQUESTS.CUSREG_ID=4

But when I join with other table with to get more information, I use 2 inner join because this is 2 foreign key from  `ELVM_SMUNT_CUS`  table it gives me 120 results

```
select * from OA_SERVICE_REQUESTS  
inner join ELVM_SMUNT_CUS T1 on OA_SERVICE_REQUESTS.DIVCOD = T1.DIVCOD 
inner join ELVM_SMUNT_CUS T2 on OA_SERVICE_REQUESTS.UNTNUM = T2.UNTNUM 
WHERE OA_SERVICE_REQUESTS.CUSREG_ID=4
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using is it mysql or Oracle?

Comment: i am using oracle

Comment: Then please remove MySQL from tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to combine them together :

```
select * from OA_SERVICE_REQUESTS R 
 inner join ELVM_SMUNT_CUS T1 on ( R.DIVCOD = T1.DIVCOD 
                              and R.UNTNUM = T1.UNTNUM )
 where R.CUSREG_ID=4;
```

for your query not to produce cross-product results.

Probably, you have 12 matching records for `R.DIVCOD = T1.DIVCOD`, and 10 matching records for `R.UNTNUM = T1.UNTNUM` for `R.CUSREG_ID=4`, by combining the result set by an `and` you can have 10results at the same time, but may yield 120 occurences by 12 times 10, if conditions are taken apart by more joins.

Comment: yes its working property . Can you tell me why it happening ?